# Can I mix cache key types when using Spring @Cacheable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching

I'm basically wondering whether I can store data in a cache using different sets of arguments as keys, such as:

```
@Cacheable(value="myCache", key="{ #itemId, #organizationId }")
public long getValue(long itemId, long organizationId) { ... }

@Cacheable(value="myCache", key="#itemName")
public long getValue(String itemName) { ... }

@Caching(evict = {
        @CacheEvict(value="myCache", key="{ #itemId, #organizationId }"),
        @CacheEvict(value="myCache", key="#itemName")
})
public void evictValue(long itemId, long organizationId , String itemName) { }
```

Or would I need to create two separate caches for this?